# How to get a value from an Enum in a view in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I have little experience on ASP.Net, so I thought I'd ask.

Trying to pass a value from an Enum in a create view so it can be passed to the database, but I just don't know how so I took a stab at it.

I have a model that has a field called pageID:

```
    public class Article
    {

       public int pageID = 0;

    }


    public class ArticleDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass a value (int type) from an enum through the view to the database:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Select Page for Insert</h2>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pageID.Equals(EnumHelper.GetSelectedItemList<PageIndex>().SelectedValue))
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input id="createButton" type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

I know the code above is causing an error, because it isn't typed out right.

Here's my enum helper, which you probably don't need to look at:

(I followed a tutorial and it is working properly)

```
public static SelectList GetSelectedItemList<T>() where T : struct
    {
        T t = default(T);
        if (!t.GetType().IsEnum) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Please make sure that T is of Enum Type"); }

        var nameList = t.GetType().GetEnumNames();

        int counter = 0;

        Dictionary<int, String> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        if (nameList != null && nameList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var name in nameList)
            {
                T newEnum = (T) Enum.Parse(t.GetType(), name);
                string description = getDescriptionFromEnumValue(newEnum as Enum);

                if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(counter))
                {
                    myDictionary.Add(counter, description);
                }
                counter++;
            }

            counter = 0;

            return new SelectList(myDictionary, "Key", "Value");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static string getDescriptionFromEnumValue(Enum value)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute =
            value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;

        return descriptionAttribute == null ? 
            value.ToString() : descriptionAttribute.Description;
    }
```

and my enum:

```
public enum PageIndex : int
{
    [Description("Developmental Disabilities Tip Sheet")]
    ddTipSheets = 1,

    [Description("Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")]
    Example1 = 2,

    [Description("I don't know what I'm doing")]
    Example2 = 3
};
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try the Enum.GetValues()

Example:

```
enum Colors{ White= 0, Pink= 100, Red= 200, Black= 300};
foreach(int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)))
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```